# Is there an API to check if an Android User has 2-Step Verification?

Tags: android, security, verification

I'm creating an application that requires a good level of security. I'm wondering if there is an API that I can check to see if a current user has 2-Step Verification on their Google Account that they are attempting to log in with. If they do, then I can use that or use a difference service.

I haven't been able to find anything so far.